# How to create a floating blob?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, modifiers, physics

I was wondering how would i get a UV Sphere to act like the floating blob in the image? 
As well as

[image: floating blob]

Answer (score 5):

## [image] ⬅ [image]

(I realised too late that this is annoyingly slow. It can be easily fixed by speeding up the Empty's animation and by increasing the number of emitted particles per unit time)

### Wobbliness

1. Add an Empty to your scene, and animate it in some ways using only rotation al location keyframes. You will use this empty to drive the coordinate space for the ripples on the blob's surface.
2. On your UV sphere, add a "Displace" modifier:

   [image]

   Set the Texture coordinates to "Object" and the Object to your Empty. Reduce the strength to around 0.4. Select "New texture" in the modifier, then go on the "texture" tab and select Type = "Clouds" and Size = 5.

   [image]
3. The empty and the Displace texture, combined, will give a result similar to this:

   [image]

### Bubbles

1. Create another UV sphere and place it on a different Layer.
2. Select your main sphere, and add a Particle System. Apart from the default values, use Emission Number = 20; Use Modifier Stack = Yes; Render type "Object"; Dupli Object = ; Size = 0.500; Random Size = 0.600; Field Weights Gravity = -1

   [image]
3. Bake the Particle cache and this is the result:

   [image]

### For enhanced smoothness

The two spheres can be Metaballs instead of UV spheres, but achieving the wobbliness would become more difficult

Comment: how would i get the eyes to blink??

Comment: sorry I only intended to address your original question (the sphere's behaviour). I don't have time right now to talk about the character animation part, but I honestly think this would be a separate question

Comment: nice, but what about the elastic/stretching effect?

Comment: Metaballs would provide that

Comment: yes, so perhaps hide a metaball under the main ball so that the bubble would look like emerging from it? You should edit your answer to add this idea

Comment: @moonboots feel free to enhance or add another answer. I don't have time to break down a metaball-based solution right now.(unfortunately one can't use a point density texture on the emitter of the particles itself, otherwise a dynamic displacement could have done the trick without adding extra objects)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Nicola Sap, another solution for the bubbles could be using metaballs. It would allow you to get the elastic/stretchy effect:

- Create a metaball and make it just a little bit smaller than your head object so that you'll never see it. Parent this metaball to the head.
- Duplicate several times this metaball, scale down the duplications and keep them inside the head. These are the bubbles.
- Move the bubbles, they will stretch when they'll get out of the first metaball, and they will seem to interact with the head.
- Give your balls enough resolution in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Metaball* > *Resolution*.

[image]