# how can i create this floating blob look with metaballs?

Tags: animation, modifiers, particles, animation-nodes, meta-objects

primarily using metaballs, how do i get this floating rippling & blinking affect?

[image: Floating Blob]

Comment: Animate smaller Metaballs within the influence of a larger one. It is going to be trial and error and you will have to animate location/translation as well as scale. Constraining the scale axis may help, so it only stretches/shrinks up/down etc.

Comment: is there away to do it procedural or with particles?

Comment: yes and no. You can use Metaballs as the objects in particles and particles can be constrained to patterns with force fields and Boid simulations but it still might not create exactly what you want. That said, do try a negative force field with a particle emitter.

Comment: This is very similar to your [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119019/how-to-create-a-floating-blob) from which one answer suggests using meta-balls, and now this question, which IMO without any added info (except a request that the answer uses metaballs) is no different.

Comment: What have you tried and what results have you gotten - and where are you stuck - in following the answer to your previous similar question?

Comment: yes it would be good to know what you tried from your previous question and what works or doesn't work